# Converting TextView to String (kind of) Android

Tags: android, string, textview

I have an object on my main.xml layout file called thefact that is TextView. I also have a string called sharefact. I want to save what text is in the TextView into the sharefact string. I can't do:

```
sharefact = thefact
```

Or anything similar to that because it would want me to convert sharefact into a textview.

Thanks!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Getting text from a `TextView` returns `CharSequence`. To convert `CharSequence` to `String`, `toString()` function is used.

```
String sharedFact = theFact.getText().toString();
```

Comment: How is this done using Kotlin?

Comment: It doesn't work. Please check my problem. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71899667/trying-to-get-calendar-data-into-a-string#71899667)

Answer (score 37):

```
TextView theFact = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.theFact);
String shareFact = theFact.getText().toString();
```

Comment: Thanks... again! You answered my last question too!

Comment: It doesn't work. Please check my problem. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71899667/trying-to-get-calendar-data-into-a-string#71899667)