# Android -TextView to String

Tags: android, string, textview

i have two text views in my linear layout and dynamically text get displayed.
Now how to convert that text view to a string in my application.

Comment: You can use `TextView.getText().toString();`

Comment: you can get the string value like `textView.getText().toString()`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting TextView to String (kind of) Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928864/converting-textview-to-string-kind-of-android)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

suppose your textview name is tv1 then try

```
String input = tv1.getText().toString();
```

Comment: How would this be done using Kotlin?

Answer (score 1):

You cant change textview to string but you can get string from textview.
This is for textview:

```
TextView textView;
textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_1);
textView.setText("AFJHDFGKS");
```

then to get text as string:

```
String text = textView.getText().toString();
```