# Trying to get Calendar data into a String [Solved]

Tags: java, android, android-datepicker, java.util.calendar

Trying to store data into a string.

This is my utilities.

```
public class CommonDatePicker {

public static  void datePicker(final TextView textView, Context context) {
  Calendar dateCalender = Calendar.getInstance();
  final int year = dateCalender.get(Calendar.YEAR);
  final   int month = dateCalender.get(Calendar.MONTH);
  final int day = dateCalender.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


  DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;
  datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(context, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
     @Override
     public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        monthOfYear = monthOfYear + 1;
        //2001-05-03
        // dayOfMonth  monthOfYear
        String formattedMonth = "" + monthOfYear;
        String formattedDayOfMonth = "" + dayOfMonth;

        if(monthOfYear < 10){

           formattedMonth = "0" + monthOfYear;
        }
        if(dayOfMonth < 10){

           formattedDayOfMonth  = "0" + dayOfMonth ;
        }
        //editText.setText( formattedDayOfMonth + "-" + formattedMonth + "-" + year);
        textView.setText( year + "-" + formattedMonth + "-" + formattedDayOfMonth);

     }

  }, year, month, day);
  datePickerDialog.setTitle("SELECT DATE");
  datePickerDialog.show();
   }
 }
```

This is where I'm trying to get data. After clicking on textView the datePicker appears as expected but I want to store picked data into a string. I don't know how to do it.

This is my main.java

```
txt_data_collection_date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            CommonDatePicker.datePicker(txt_data_collection_date, TofsilForm10Activity.this);
            //String date; I want to store data in date.
        }
    });
```

Comment: Doesn't your implementation of `DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener` you showed do what you want, store the chosen date as text in `textView`? The purpose of your second piece of code eludes me.

Comment: Yes. It's showing the date that has been picked but I want to store it on a string.

Comment: You already generate a string, and store that string within `textView`. If you want to assign it somewhere else, why can't you do that within your `onDateSet` method?

Comment: Can you please show me how?

Answer (score 2):

Caveat, I am not an Android developer, so this may be a silly Answer.

---

By the way, the terrible `Calendar` class was supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Android 26+ comes with an implementation. For earlier Android, the latest tooling makes most of the *java.time* functionality available via “API desugaring”.

Replace this:

```java
Calendar dateCalender = Calendar.getInstance();
final int year = dateCalender.get(Calendar.YEAR);
final   int month = dateCalender.get(Calendar.MONTH);
final int day = dateCalender.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

… with the following use of [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html). And note that unlike the legacy classes, *java.time* uses sane numbering with the year 2022 being 2022, and January-December being 1-12.

```java
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.now() ;
final int year = ld.getYear() ;
final int month = ld.getMonthValue() ;
final int day = ld.getDayOfMonth() ;
```

The format you want for your text happens to comply with [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. That standard’s formats are used by default in the *java.time* classes when generating/parsing text. So replace all this:

```java
        monthOfYear = monthOfYear + 1;
        //2001-05-03
        // dayOfMonth  monthOfYear
        String formattedMonth = "" + monthOfYear;
        String formattedDayOfMonth = "" + dayOfMonth;

        if(monthOfYear < 10){

           formattedMonth = "0" + monthOfYear;
        }
        if(dayOfMonth < 10){

           formattedDayOfMonth  = "0" + dayOfMonth ;
        }
        //editText.setText( formattedDayOfMonth + "-" + formattedMonth + "-" + year);
        textView.setText( year + "-" + formattedMonth + "-" + formattedDayOfMonth);
```

… with this:

```java
        textView.setText( LocalDate.of( year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth ).toString() ) ;
```

So that first piece of code could look like this. Notice how better indenting makes the code more obvious.

```java
public class CommonDatePicker
{
    public static void datePicker ( final TextView textView , Context context )
    {
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog =
                new DatePickerDialog(
                        context ,
                        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()  // Implementing `DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener`.
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onDateChanged ( DatePicker view , int year , int monthOfYear , int dayOfMonth )
                            {
                                textView.setText( LocalDate.of( year , monthOfYear , dayOfMonth ).toString() );
                            }
                        } ,
                        today.getYear() ,
                        today.getMonth() ,
                        today.getDayOfMonth()
                );
        datePickerDialog.setTitle( "SELECT DATE" );
        datePickerDialog.show();
    }
}
```

Having revamped that code, let's address your question, which apparently is that you want to save the user's chosen date into another place. I am just guessing at that given (a) your Comments, and (b) I cannot determine the purpose of your second code snippet.

Your `onDateChanged` method reacts to the user choosing a date in the date picker. There you generate your desired text. You store that text in `textView`. You could store it somewhere else too.

```java
                            @Override
                            public void onDateChanged ( DatePicker view , int year , int monthOfYear , int dayOfMonth )
                            {
                                LocalDate chosenDate = LocalDate.of( year , monthOfYear , dayOfMonth ) ;
                                someOtherObject.someField = chosenDate.toString() ;
                                textView.setText( chosenDate.toString() );
                            }
```

Better yet, store the `LocalDate` on that other place, rather than mere text.

```java
                            @Override
                            public void onDateChanged ( DatePicker view , int year , int monthOfYear , int dayOfMonth )
                            {
                                LocalDate chosenDate = LocalDate.of( year , monthOfYear , dayOfMonth ) ;
                                someOtherObject.someField = chosenDate ;
                                textView.setText( chosenDate.toString() );
                            }
```

Of course, global variables like `someOtherObject.someField` should generally be avoided. So pass it in just like you passed in `TextView textView`.

```
public void datePicker ( final LocalDate someLocalDateField, final TextView textView , Context context )
```

Perhaps a better approach is to make use of the `CommonDatePicker` class you have created. Change that `datePicker` method to be an instance method, not a `static` method. Add a member field to that class to carry the result of a user’s choice. And I would change the name of that method to be more descriptive such as `makeDatePicker`.

Kill the `show` call. Interrogate for the result afterwards.

```java
public class CommonDatePicker
{
    private LocalDate chosenDate ;
    public LocalDate getChosenDate() { return this.chosenDate ; }
    public void makeDatePicker ( final TextView textView , Context context )
    {
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog =
                new DatePickerDialog(
                        context ,
                        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()  // Implementing `DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener`.
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onDateChanged ( DatePicker view , int year , int monthOfYear , int dayOfMonth )
                            {
                                this.chosenDate = LocalDate.of( year , monthOfYear , dayOfMonth ) ;
                                textView.setText( this.chosenDate.toString() );
                            }
                        } ,
                        today.getYear() ,
                        today.getMonth() ,
                        today.getDayOfMonth()
                );
        datePickerDialog.setTitle( "SELECT DATE" );
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
CommonDatePicker commonDatePicker = new CommonDatePicker( context ) ;
DatePickerDialog datePicker = commonDatePicker.makeDatePicker() ;
datePicker.show() ;  // I assume this code blocks here until date picker is closed. (I don't know Android.)
LocalDate chosenDate = commonDatePicker.getChosenDate() ;
```

If the situation is such that the user may cancel the date picker without making a choice, then our `LocalDate` reference variable will be null. You could check for null. But better to return an `Optional` to indicate explicitly that null is an acceptable value value to be expected.

```
public Optional < LocalDate > getChosenDate() { return Optional.ofNullable ( this.chosenDate ) ; }
```

Usage:

```
CommonDatePicker commonDatePicker = new CommonDatePicker( context ) ;
DatePickerDialog datePicker = commonDatePicker.makeDatePicker() ;
datePicker.show() ;  // I assume this code blocks here until date picker is closed. (I don't know Android.)
LocalDate date = commonDatePicker.getChosenDate().orElse( existingLocalDate ) ;
```

Now we no longer need to pass in `final TextView textView`. Change your class to this.

```java
public class CommonDatePicker
{
    private LocalDate chosenDate ;
    public Optional < LocalDate > getChosenDate() { return Optional.ofNullable( this.chosenDate ) ; }
    public void makeDatePicker ( Context context )
    {
        LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
        DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog =
                new DatePickerDialog(
                        context ,
                        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()  // Implementing `DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener`.
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onDateChanged ( DatePicker view , int year , int monthOfYear , int dayOfMonth )
                            {
                                this.chosenDate = LocalDate.of( year , monthOfYear , dayOfMonth ) ;
                            }
                        } ,
                        today.getYear() ,
                        today.getMonth() ,
                        today.getDayOfMonth()
                );
        datePickerDialog.setTitle( "SELECT DATE" );
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
CommonDatePicker commonDatePicker = new CommonDatePicker( context ) ;
DatePickerDialog datePicker = commonDatePicker.makeDatePicker() ;
datePicker.show() ;  
LocalDate localDate = commonDatePicker.getChosenDate().orElse( existingLocalDate ) ;
someOtherPlace.updateDate( localDate ) ;
textView.setText( localDate.toString() ) ;
```

After all these changes, notice how we have pulled outside of `CommonDatePicker` all the parts that are extraneous. Now that class can “mind its own business”, without knowing or caring about other pieces of your app. Its job is simply to gather input from the user, not update various parts of your app.

We could further simplify the code, so the calling app does not need to know about the use of `DatePickerDialog`. We could drop the `makeDatePicker()`, and add a `show` method instead. With a `show` method in place, we can skip the interrogation step, and just have `show` return the `Optional < LocalDate >` object.

And rather than assume the dialog should initialize to today's date, accept a date in its constructor.

```java
public class CommonDatePicker
{
    private DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;
    private LocalDate chosenDate;

    public CommonDatePicker ( final Context context , final LocalDate initialDate )
    {
        this.datePickerDialog =
                new DatePickerDialog(
                        context ,
                        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()  // Implementing `DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener`.
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onDateChanged ( DatePicker view , int year , int monthOfYear , int dayOfMonth )
                            {
                                this.chosenDate = LocalDate.of( year , monthOfYear , dayOfMonth );
                            }
                        } ,
                        initialDate.getYear() ,
                        initialDate.getMonth() ,
                        initialDate.getDayOfMonth()
                );
        this.datePickerDialog.setTitle( "SELECT DATE" );
    }

    public Optional < LocalDate > show ( ) { 
        this.datePickerDialog.show() ;  // I assume code blocks here until user choses a date. (I don't know Android.)
        return Optional.ofNullable( this.chosenDate ); 
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
LocalDate yesterday = LocalDate.now().minusDays( 1 ) ;
Optional < LocalDate > optionalChosenDate = new CommonDatePicker( context , yesterday ).show() ;
someOtherPlace.updateDate( optionalChosenDate.orElse( yesterday ) ) ;
textView.setText( optionalChosenDate.orElse( yesterday ).toString() ) ;
```

Now the calling programmer need know nothing about the `DatePickerDialog` we happen to be using internally in our `CommonDatePicker` class. The calling programmer needs to learn only our simple API. That API consists of two parts: A constructor taking a `Context` and a `LocalDate`, and a `show` method that interacts with user to return an optional `LocalDate` object.

Answer (score 0):

All I had to do was this:

```
String stDate = txt_data_collection_date.getText().toString();
```

Add the above code here

```
txt_data_collection_date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        CommonDatePicker.datePicker(txt_data_collection_date, TofsilForm10Activity.this);
        String stDate = txt_data_collection_date.getText().toString(); //Problem Solved
    }
});
```